# Collinearity Criterion in euclidean geometry

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

#### Problem setting

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space.

We will say that $l\subset M$ is a *line* if there is a surjective function $f:\mathbb{R}\to l$ such that $d(f(x),f(y))=|x-y|$.

If $l$ is a line, being $f$ its asociated function, we will say that the set $f[x,y]\subset l$ is a *segment* with endpoints $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.

Then, suppose that the following properties hold:

1. Given two poitns $P$ and $Q$, there is an unique line $l$ such that $P$, $Q\in l$.
2. Given a line $l$, $M\setminus l=U\cup V$, where $U$ and $V$ are nonempty disjoint convex sets. Also, if a segment has one endpoint in $U$ and the other in $V$, the segment intersects $l$. $U$ and $V$ will be called *opposite sides* of $l$.
3. For each line $l$ with opposite sides $U$ and $V$, there exists an isometry $\tau_l$ such that $\tau_l|_{l}=\text{id}$ and $\tau_{l}(U)=V$, $\tau_l(V)=U$. We will say that $\tau_l$ is a *reflection* around $l$.

This is just the setting for euclidean geometry given in [this abstract](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.uwm.edu/dist/0/158/files/2016/11/3.-2-dimensional-axiomatic-geometry-revisited.Outline-1668m8c.pdf).

#### The problem itself

> I am trying to prove that if $A$, $B$, $C$ are three distinct points such that $d(A,C)=d(A,B)+d(B,C)$, then they are collinear.

#### My approach

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three non collinear points such that $d(A,C)=d(A,B)+d(B,C)$. Consider the point $D$ in the segment $\overline{AC}$ such that $d(A,D)=d(A,B)$. Also, let $B'$ be the reflection of $B$ over the line $l:=\overleftrightarrow{AC}$, as long as $B$ and $B'$ are in opposite sides of $l$, the segment $\overline{BB'}$ intersects $l$ in $B^*$.

Let's assume that $d(A,B^*)>d(A,D)$, then
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
d(B,B')&\leq d(B,A)+d(A,B')=2d(A,B)=2d(A,D)\\&<2d(A,B^*)=d(B,B')\text{, }
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
so, obviously $d(A,B^*)\leq d(A,D)$, and, it is easy to conclude that if $d(A,B^*)= d(A,D)$ then
\begin{equation}
d(A,B^*)=d(B,A)=d(B,C)=d(B,B^*)=d(B^*,C)\text{, }
\end{equation}
from here, I really don't know how to proceed, it seems that a contradiction will arise, but I don't see how.

Comment: I haven't written out the details, but it looks easier to proceed directly than by contradiction/contraposition: Consider the unique lines through $AB$, $AC$, and $BC$; then use uniqueness to show the segment of line $AC$ with endpoints $A$ and $B$ is the segment of line $AB$ with endpoints $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang But maybe there is no segment in line $AC$ with endpoints $A$ and $B$, this is the very thing we are trying to prove.

Comment: I didn't say that well: The suggested idea is to show the union of the segment $AB$ and the segment $BC$ is (because it's a union of segments, and the total length is the distance from $A$ to $C$) a segment from $A$ to $C$, hence _the_ segment $AC$. But again, I haven't tried to write out the details.